# Comparing a list with two tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, tuples

I want to compare the first element in my list "i" with my first tuple "i0_prior" and by compare I mean to check if it is close to (+-a) the numbers in the tuple. The same applies to the second element and the 2nd tuple "i1_prior".
I hardcoded it because the tuples were "only" 20 numbers wide. But is there a more suited way to do it?

```
    for i in blured[0, :]:
            if (i[0] in range(i0_prior[0]-a, i0_prior[0]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[0]-b, i1_prior[0]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[1]-a, i0_prior[1]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[1]-b, i1_prior[1]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[2]-a, i0_prior[2]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[2]-b, i1_prior[2]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[3]-a, i0_prior[3]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[3]-b, i1_prior[3]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[4]-a, i0_prior[4]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[4]-b, i1_prior[4]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[5]-a, i0_prior[5]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[5]-b, i1_prior[5]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[6]-a, i0_prior[6]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[6]-b, i1_prior[6]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[7]-a, i0_prior[7]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[7]-b, i1_prior[7]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[8]-a, i0_prior[8]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[8]-b, i1_prior[8]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[9]-a, i0_prior[9]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[9]-b, i1_prior[9]-b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[10]-a, i0_prior[10]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[10]-b, i1_prior[10]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[11]-a, i0_prior[11]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[11]-b, i1_prior[11]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[12]-a, i0_prior[12]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[12]-b, i1_prior[12]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[13]-a, i0_prior[13]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[13]-b, i1_prior[13]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[14]-a, i0_prior[14]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[14]-b, i1_prior[14]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[15]-a, i0_prior[15]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[15]-b, i1_prior[15]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[16]-a, i0_prior[16]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[16]-b, i1_prior[16]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[17]-a, i0_prior[17]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[17]-b, i1_prior[17]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[18]-a, i0_prior[18]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[18]-b, i1_prior[18]+b) or
                    i[0] in range(i0_prior[19]-a, i0_prior[19]+a) and i[1] in range(i1_prior[19]-b, i1_prior[19]+b)):
```

And yes the and operator is needed here, because the positions in both tuples are kinda "linked".

Comment: I'm trying to analyze a video so both of my tuples are slighlty changing each frame, but here is an example: ...... Edit: Sorry thought pressing enter jumps to the next line, silly me

Comment: update your question with the example. No example posted yet

Comment: i: [376 106 7] ////// i0_prior =  [526, 235, 424, 534, 234, 237, 342, 123, 541, 125, 643, 764, 453, 375, 534, 231, 123, 523, 128, 834] ///// i1_prior = [213, 345, 643, 126, 456, 104, 523, 632, 805, 243, 653, 734, 734, 682, 143, 723, 624, 654, 213, 312]

Comment: You need to update the question. Edit the question. Do not put the example in the comments section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to `zip` the two tuples together:

```
for i in blured:
    if any(
        i[0] in range(prior0-a, prior0+a)
        and i[1] in range(prior1-b, prior1-b)
        for prior0, prior1 in zip(i0_prior, i1_prior)
    ):
        # do thing
```

You could also iterate over `range(20)`:

```
for i in blured:
    if any(
        i[0] in range(i0_prior[n]-a, i0_prior[n]+a)
        and i[1] in range(i1_prior[n]-b, i1_prior[n]-b)
        for n in range(20)
    ):
        # do thing
```